# Moving a child MC to stage but remaining its animation

Tags: actionscript-3, depth

Is it possible to remain an on going animation on a child MC while moving the MC to the stage (same level as its parents)

If by using removeChild and addChild again the animation will not be consistancy.

Comment: This, dear @Bakapii, is an answer :)

Comment: @Kodiak you're right, and I've turned it into one. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to removeChild/addChild if you're just changing parents. Just calling addChild on a child that already has a parent, will re-parent the child automatically.

I haven't tested your exact problem. But if the MovieClip stops playing when you call addChild, you could just store the current frame and then resume playing from that frame after you've called addChild. Like this:

```
var frameNumber : int = myMovieClip.currentFrame;
newParent.addChild(myMovieClip);
myMovieClip.gotoAndPlay(frameNumber);
```